# Registering for RConnectionMonitor events causes thread to panic

Tags: qt, events, symbian, symbian3

I have a custom observer class derived from `CBase`, `MConnectionMonitorObserver`, and `QObject`(for signals) that I use to observe events from `RConnectionMonitor`.

When I call the `RConnectionMonitor::NotifyEventL` passing the observer instance, the application crashes saying that a thread has panicked.

What I'm trying to do here is to listen to the network events asynchronously without blocking the main thread.

**EDIT: Should I use an active object to hold the RConnectionMonitor object?**

Best regards

Comment: Category: KERN-EXEC; Reason: 0

Comment: This means you are using a bad handle. Are you opening the connection successfully?

Comment: I can successfully use RConnectionMonitor using the Get*Attribute calls, so I guess my handle should be ok?

Comment: @James It seems that I connected just after i called NotifyEventL, which caused the panic. Please format your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as @James commented, that I was registering for events before I established the connection to the connection monitor server.